# CopyPNGFile: Can't find Default.png

Tags: xcode

I recently migrated launch images to an Asset Catalog but am getting this error:

**CopyPNGFile**

Can't find /Path/To/App/Default.png
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng failed with exit code 1

I deleted the Default.png in the root path and can see I have a version in the Asset Catalog (e.g. by using `Show in Finder`).

Why can't Xcode find these images?

Answer (score 5):

It seems there is a dangling reference to the file in `Build phases` tab of your target in `Copy Bundle Resrouces` section.

This is how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cmUm.png - just find red entry in the list and delete it.

---

**update**

Make sure you have migrated your launch image to assets catalog too.

[image]

Comment: I don't have any dangling references - there are no red entries in the list.

Comment: Did you set launch images source in target settings? (see the update)